# When will the following union of topologies be a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{\mathfrak{T}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be a family of topologies on $X$. Then we know that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\mathfrak{T}_\alpha$ is also a topology on $X$. But $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\mathfrak{T}_\alpha$ is not a topology on $X$ in general. In fact it can be shown that even the finite union of topologies is also not a topology in general (for example, take $X\supset\{a,b\}$ with $a\ne b$ consider the topologies $\mathfrak{T}_1:=\{X,\{a\},\emptyset\}$ and $\mathfrak{T}_2:=\{X,\{b\},\emptyset\}$).

My questions are,

> Let $\{\mathfrak{T}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be a family of topologies on $X$. Then what is a necessary and sufficient condition on $X$ or on $\{\mathfrak{T}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ (in the inclusive sense) such that,
>
> 1. $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in I_0}\mathfrak{T}_\alpha$ is a topology on $X$ where $I_0$ is a finite subset of $I$.
> 2. $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\mathfrak{T}_\alpha$ is a topology on $X$.
> 3. There exists a subset (which is not a singleton subset) $J$ of $I$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}\mathfrak{T}_\alpha$ is a topology on $X$.

Comment: To find answers on 1) and 2) you can just apply the defining properties of a topology.

Comment: You should note that, in the example you give, the union *is* a topology: the discrete topology (I'm assuming you mean $X = \{a,b\}$). Also I expect it is considered bad form to link to answers you previously haven't liked. One of the purposes of this site is for people with similar questions to be able to look at what is already posted. Just because you didn't find something helpful, doesn't mean someone else won't. Finally, for 3) I think you should probably insist that $J$ contains more than one element, otherwise a singleton will work.

Comment: @James: Thanks for noting the typo and thanks also for the suggestion regarding $J$. By the way, regarding the answer that I have linked, I have linked the answer only to show example of what **I consider** to be an unhelpful answer to this question and not to receive an answer of that type. Do you think that restricting this type of answer is a bad practice? If so, please tell me, I will surely remove the link, if I find your explanation plausible.

Comment: I think, if you dig around in the meta, it is generally accepted that an answer to a question that, say, uses powerful methods that the OP doesn't know about are perfectly acceptable as answers to the question. The OP need not accept them, but, it may help some later person who has the same question as the OP *and* knows the powerful  methods. To address the particular answer you didn't like, it seems the poster was answering what you had literally written (initially), which is not the same as what you initially meant.

Comment: Yes, I know that is what you think, I read the exchange in the comments. I was just giving an example of an answer that an OP may find unhelpful, but is still considered a valid response in this space. If you want to know what the community thinks, you could make a meta-post yourself. I could be wrong about the etiquette.

Comment: IMHO your comment with link is misplaced. You might once have received an answer that was not useful for you, but so what? It might be useful for others (or become useful for you later). There is definitely no threat that this will happen again and again. Also an answer that is not useful will not chase away useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any topology on $\Omega$, and set $Y_x = \{\emptyset, x, \Omega\}$ for $x\in X$. (i.e. here $I = X$). Note $X = \bigcup_x Y_x$, and $Z = \bigcup_{x\in F} Y_x$ is a topology if and only if $F\cup\{\emptyset, \Omega\} \subset X$ is a topology. You can't hope for a characterization, in general

As for finite unions, a sufficient condition is that one of the topologies includes all the others, but it is not necessary, as demonstrated by taking $X = \mathcal P(\Omega)$ for $|\Omega| < \infty$ in the above.

Comment: I do feel it's a little confusing to essentially invert the notation of the OP, $X$ was the set with a topology, now in your answer $X$ is the topology. It's fine but initially it is a little confusing.